# TypeORM does not add foreign key on a column

Tags: orm, typeorm

This is the first time I will be using `typeorm` in a project.

I am trying to add a foreign key on an `entity`, but when it is generated as a table. I cannot see a relationship/foreign key bound to that column.

Here's the sample entity:

**Locale.ts**

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm";

@Entity('Locale')
export class Locale {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    ID: number;

    @Column()
    Name: string;

    @Column()
    LanguageCode: string;
}
```

**TranslationTitle.ts**

```
import { Locale } from './../locale/Locale';
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from "typeorm";

@Entity('TranslationTitle')
export class TranslationTitle {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    ID: number;

    @Column()
    CreatedBy: string;

    @Column()
    CreatedDate: string;

    @Column()
    Status: boolean;

    @Column()
    ModifiedBy: string;

    @Column()
    ModifiedDate: string;

    @Column()
    Text: string;

    @Column()
    @OneToMany(type => Locale, locale => locale.ID)
    Locale: number;

}
```

So what I am expecting on this code is for the `Locale` column to be a foreign key of `ID` field of `Locale` table.

But when I look at the generated table, there's no relationship between the two fields.

[image]
[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Your TranslationTitle has at most 1 Locale, so it is a ManyToOne mapping not a OneToMany (many titles for 1 locale). Also your field is incorrectly defined as it should not be a number but a Locale type.

```
@Column()
@ManyToOne(type => Locale, {
    nullable: true
})
Locale: Locale;
```